# Python: Adding values to a list and then appending this list to a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing lists, each representing a company, with EBITDA values inside. Now I want to take the log of the returns and create a new list that has all the log returns using:

```
ln(ebitda t / ebitda t-1)
```

The desired result would be a list inside a list that keeps each company's results together like so:

```
[[0.69314718055994529, 0.40546510810816438, 0.28768207245178085], [0.18232155679395459, 0.15415067982725836, 0.13353139262452257]]
```

but so far I am getting:

```
[0.69314718055994529, 0.40546510810816438, 0.28768207245178085, 0.18232155679395459, 0.15415067982725836, 0.13353139262452257]
```

I found a way on SO to loop through each list and make the calculations like below:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

import numpy as np

l = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

logs = []
for num in l:
    for x, y in zip_longest(num[1:], num[0:-1]):
        logs.append(np.log((x/y)))
```

However, for the results to be usable I need to be able to get them back into their own lists and I am not sure how to do this.

Thank you for reading and any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by get them back into their own lists?

Comment: @gggg In my code the end result was that all the log returns are combined into one big list. With one massive list there is no easy way to calculate for example the mean or std of each individual company. I need the returns per company in their own list which now works with Adirio's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

l = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

logs = []

for enterprise in l:
    logs.append([])
    for i in range(1, len(enterprise)):
        logs[-1].append(np.log(enterprise[i]/enterprise[i-1]))
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. Just for the sake of my understanding, we are looping over the list, appending an empty list for each list and then inside that list we append the log return. Is that about right?

Comment: Right, thats exactly what we are doing. The inner loop is skipping element 0 (by using `range(1, ...)` instead of `range(...)`) as we need the previous EBITDA value and the first element doesn't have a previous EBITDA. The rest are 2 simple loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cleaner version of what you have, but I don't understand the statement about getting them back into their own lists. Maybe iterating over `l2` is what you want?

```
import numpy as np

l = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
def f(num):
      return [np.log(num[i+1]/float(num[i])) for i in xrange(len(num)-1)]
l2 = [f(num) for num in l]

for logren in l2:
      print(logren)
```